# Python3, search for a value in a dict

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have this dict variable:

```
result = {'result': [{'code': 'switch', 'value': False}, {'code': 'battery_percentage', 'value': 100}, {'code': 'time_use', 'value': 4370}, {'code': 'weather_delay', 'value': 'cancel'}, {'code': 'countdown', 'value': 563}, {'code': 'work_state', 'value': 'idle'}, {'code': 'smart_weather', 'value': 'sunny'}, {'code': 'use_time_one', 'value': 602}], 'success': True, 't': 1647114301811, 'tid': '521dc986a3654ecaff3b6da7a08cf3a'}
```

I just need to search for the value of the first 'switch', but apparently all my tests went wrong.

How can I get the boolean value of the "switch"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stop the search at the first valid entry, you could use `next` and a generator expression:

```
next(d.get('value') for d in result['result'] if d.get('code')=='switch')
```

Output:

```
False
```